# How can I define variables for several columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm creating a program that returns different statistics form any file  uploaded (with a certain data structure).

I need to write some code that allows to define variables for the columns in each file, the problem is that in some cases there are 5 columns and in others 7, 8 or more.

Any thoughts? Maybe with a for loop?

I expect the program to read all the columns and name them x1, x2, x3 and so on.

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with Pandas, but the question itself is very unclear. You should give at least some kind of representative example and what you have tried yourself to solve the issue. What does "define variables for the columns" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify the names of the headers then pandas will infer them.  You can change them after you read them if you like or you can force them to be what you want.

For instance, letting pandas infer the header names and then renaming them X1...

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv',header=None)
df 

    0   1   2   3   4   #<- Header names given by pandas
0   1   2   3   4   5

df.columns = [f"X{_}" for _ in df.index]
    X0  X1  X2  X3  X4
0   1   2   3   4   5
```

Or if you want to give each column a specific name, something like

```
df.columns = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz', 'Biz', 'Boo']
    Foo Bar Baz Biz Boo
0   1   2   3   4   5
```

Or if you prefer to ensure that all data has 8 columns regardless of what the user passed in.  In this case you will get NaN in the unfilled columns

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv',header=None,names=['X1','X2','X3','X4','X5','X6','X7','X8'])
    X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7  X8
0   1   2   3   4   5   NaN NaN NaN
```

No matter how you code it, you have columns with the names you provide or the ones pandas provides.

```
df['Foo'] == df[1] == df['X1']
```

Comment: It's a good solution, the problem is that I'll need the headers after to name the variables in order to plot them.
Do you have any other ideas?
My idea was to name the variables as x1, x2, x3... and save the original column name in each variable

Comment: @NicoGandolfo your understanding is off. You should look into how to plot dataframes, you don't need to "name the variables"

Comment: @roganjosh I know how to plot them. It's just that I'm trying to develop a program that will help my coworkers to get different statistics and then plot.

Comment: @NicoGandolfo "the problem is that I'll need the headers after to name the variables in order to plot them." You just don't have a clear problem statement at all in that case.

Comment: @NicoGandolfo, the headers can be named whatever you want as I showed in the second example.  I just happened to name them x1 - x8, you can name them whatever you like if they are not part of the file.  You can then access them using standard slicing notation such as `df['X1']`

Comment: Or, you can use the first example and rename them after you import them.  In this case again, I just named them X1 - X4.  I'd edit the answer to show something more clear